# How to stop url re-direct to your server

Tags: domain, redirection, domain-name

Let's assume I own a domain www.abcd.com

Someone else owns a domain www.wxyz.com

Someone else is pointing all requests of his domain (www.wxyz.com) to my domain www.abcd.com

Is there any way I can stop all traffic from www.wxyz.com to www.abcd.com ?

Comment: You can't do this at the DNS level, but you should be able to at the webserver, what webserver software are you using?

Comment: I'm using apache webserver

Comment: .htaccess to the rescue http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-referrer/

Comment: @alex somehow htaccess solution is not working

Comment: @alex ; Thank You. Finally I managed to get it done using .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking it that you are saying someone has changed their DNS records to point to the same IP address as your domain.  You also mention that you are using Apache.

Incoming HTTP requests have a `Host:` header that identifies the domain they are being sent to, in plain text.

Apache lets you host multiple "virtual" sites on a single webserver.  You can actually have multiple DNS domains pointing to the same IP, and Apache can serve out a different `DocumentRoot` depending on what domain is accessed.  This works because of how the client sends the `Host:` header above.

So all you have to do is create another `VirtualHost` with the offending domain, and you can either `302 Redirect` it back to the original site by IP if you know it, or you can create a small site that has a message telling hapless users what is going on, or even do something nasty like spoof the offender's entire original site.

Comment: Is it good idea to create the DNS zone and then put it on local loop i.e 127.0.0.1

Comment: I tried htaccess solution ; it's not working. Also I contacted my server admin... as per him option to create another VirtualHost with offending domain is not working... can you please help to point to related documentation ?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Comment: Can you please help me to get documentation related to your comment: "or you can create a small site that has a message telling hapless users what is going on" ?

Comment: Is this what you are referring ? $visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (preg_match("/IP OF offender/",$visitor)) {
      header('Location: http://www.abc.com/nastypage');
} else {
      header('Location: http://www.abc.com/realpage');